# jQuery Post not getting a xml response

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery post request, how can i get back xml response, I checked in fiddler the response is coming as my expected xml

Here is my jquery post

```
$.post("/csm/viewall.action",
  { sessiontoken:   sessiontoken },
      function(xml)
      {
            alert(xml);
      }
);
```

alert returns `[object XMLDocument]`

My xml

```
<list>
<com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<cfgId>83</cfgId>
<cfgName>test</cfgName>
<cfgDesc>test</cfgDesc>
<cfgType>test</cfgType>
<fileName>csmclientbenz.xml</fileName>
<absolutePath>../webapps/csm/files//1-105101/csmclientbenz.xml</absolutePath>
</com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<cfgId>82</cfgId>
<cfgName>test1</cfgName>
<cfgDesc>test2</cfgDesc>
<cfgType>test1</cfgType>
<fileName>csmclientbenz.xml</fileName>
<absolutePath>../webapps/csm/files//1-105101/csmclientbenz.xml</absolutePath>
</com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<list>
```

Comment: `XMLDocument` is what you want. Don't get your problem.

Comment: Clearly it is working then...

Comment: I can't answer your question, but i can recommend JSON over XML for this kinda stuff, less hassle and less traffic. If possible of course.

Comment: @DanielB: In Fiddler i can get my response as xml buton page alert i get XMLDocument, instead i want the xml text itself

Comment: @Ricky You should have said that in your question.

Comment: @3nigma: i updated my question with my xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an informative post about parsing the xml with jquery

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

you can read the xml as

```
$(xml).find('com.abc.db.ConfigInfo').each(function(){
var ths = $(this);
var id= ths.find('cfgId').text();
var name = ths.find('cfgName').text();
....//and so on

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your line of code to this:

`alert($(xml).find('list').html());`

Comment: Try the update. Replace `rootElement` with the appropriate string

Answer (score 1):

You *are* getting the XML back. It's in the form of an XMLDocument object.

You can then use `jQuery(xml)` to create a jQuery object that you can go on to manipulate with the standard jQuery methods.

Comment: are you saying something like `xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);`

Comment: @Rickey: No. You don't need to parse the XML. You already have an XMLDocument. I mean: `var xmlDoc  = $(xml)`

Answer (score 0):

It is failing try to catch the success event and error event with:

```
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: That is not what is happening. The inline callback IS ALWAYS the success function.